# Why am I getting a zsh: exec format error?

Tags: zsh

I am trying to run the metal executable from my zsh terminal in order to meta-analyze GWAS data. I have the executable in the correct directory and have checked that it is not 0MB due to truncation.

Reproducible:
Download the Linux file from http://csg.sph.umich.edu/abecasis/metal/download/

In terminal:

```
PATH TO EXECUTABLE ./metal
zsh: exec format error: ./metal
```

Comment: I am having the same error after the last oh-mh-zsh update, but with another execuatable.

Answer (score 38):

You probably install wrong OS of go, for example, you might install go for MacOS in Linux

I solve this problem by installing go for correct OS

Edit: also, you may got the right OS but the wrong architecture:

[image: zsh error for architecture mismatch]

Answer (score 1):

The executable has been pre-compiled on a certain distribution with libraries at a certain places at certain versions.

If you have a different distribution, libraries versions, it won't work and you better compile from the source.

Basically what you have to do is to download and extract the sources, go in the folder and execute `make`. (You will have probably to install `make` first.)

I think that's not your job at all so maybe you can find a geeky person to help you, because you may stumble upon problems, libraries to install, old versions not supported anymore, new versions not supported yet...

Answer (score 1):

In case if it helps anyone, in my case I had an environment variable  GOOS=linux and trying to build it on Mac and got this error.

unset GOOS fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I emptied an executable by mistake.

```
~>true > a
~>wc -c a
0 a
~>./a
zsh: exec format error: ./a
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting up **Hugo** (static site generator) on my machine which has *amd64* architecture, but in the release list of its binaries on the GitHub, I mistakenly downloaded the binary compiled against the *arm64* and I got the exact same message.

The crux of the message is that such type of errors occur when the platform against which the binary you are trying to execute has been compiled doesn't match yours.

On Debian/Debian, you can run:

```bash
dpkg --print-architecture
```

to find out the architecture of your machine.